# Will function result passed as parameter be released in JNI?

Tags: java, memory-management, java-native-interface

So my question is concerned with memory leak in JNI.

if I have:

```
jclass cls = env->FindClass("java/lang/String");
jobjectArray aRow = env->NewObjectArray(col, cls, NULL);
env->DeleteLocalRef(cls);
```

I know cls memory will be release.  However if I use:

```
jobjectArray aRow = env->NewObjectArray(col, env->FindClass("java/lang/String"), NULL);
```

Will the jclass passed as parameter be released?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not immediately, only after your current JNI method returns to the JVM caller. Then GC will take care about it. This should not be a problem as long as you are creating a modest amount of references. JVM will tell you when your amount is not modest anymore.

However, for complete correctness, you should check the return value of `FindClass` before you use it as a parameter elsewhere. It can still return NULL in case JVM throws an exception.